# Why don't the kv file variables accept self?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How can the kv variable of a file refer to the py variable of a file using self?

The fact is that App is inherent only in classes, and self-only in functions.

The kv file variable accepts only app:

```
'''
MDFlatButton:
    id: flat
    text: app.gg
'''
```

But I need it to work like this:

```
class Test(MDApp):
    gg = '123'
MDFlatButton:
    id: flat
    text: self.gg
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        gg = '123'
```

to refer to a variable inside a function, you need self, which does not accept kv. Question: how do I make it work and not give an error?

```
MDFlatButton: 
    id: flat 
    text: self.gg
```

Or something else, but that the MDFlatButton button takes the text argument from the function.

***Help(***

Comment: You can use `self` in `kv`. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn out! This work for me:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
KV = '''
Screen:
    MDFlatButton:
        id: flat
        text: app.gg
'''
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.gg = '555'
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
Test().run()
```

don't know what i did, but this work

Answer (score 0):

you can use root

```
MDFlatButton: 
    id: flat 
    text: root.gg
```

the 2nd mistake is that u didn't set it to self.

```
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.gg = '123' # <---- was gg = '123'
```

Comment: I'm trying, but receive error: File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 695, in _apply_rule
     value, bound = create_handler(
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 245, in create_handler
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,

Comment: added another comment about setting `gg` without `self`. not sure about the error you are getting...