# Err0r in kv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Why is doesn't work?:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
KV = '''
Screen:
    MDFlatButton:
        id: flat
        text: root.gg
'''
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        gg = '123'
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
Test().run()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 242, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'gg'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 695, in _apply_rule
     value, bound = create_handler(
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 245, in create_handler
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 5:
 ...
       3:    MDFlatButton:
       4:        id: flat
 >>    5:        text: root.gg
 ...
 AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'gg'
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 242, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\FindWord.py", line 14, in <module>
     Test().run()
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\FindWord.py", line 13, in build
     return Builder.load_string(KV)
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 408, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 710, in _apply_rule
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 5:
 ...
       3:    MDFlatButton:
       4:        id: flat
 >>    5:        text: root.gg
 ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 5:
 ...
       3:    MDFlatButton:
       4:        id: flat
 >>    5:        text: root.gg
 ...
 AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'gg'
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 242, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 695, in _apply_rule
     value, bound = create_handler(
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 245, in create_handler
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
```

I need the kv file to see the variable inside the function. everyone advises to use root, but this error prevents me.
Me need use exactly 'root.gg', app not fit, because app not work when need refer to a variable in a function. Previos version of question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352373/why-dont-the-kv-file-variables-accept-self)**

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare gg at class level.
Also, instead of `root.gg` use `app.gg`

Comment: I need exactly this variable to be in the function

Comment: Variable in function should be accessible by `app.build.gg`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it can be solved as mentioned above, the code would look like this:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

KV = '''
Screen:
    MDFlatButton:
        id: flat
        text: app.gg
'''
class Test(MDApp):
        
    def build(self):
        self.gg='123'
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
Test().run()
```